# Setting Up Elastic Search for my Website

Tags: elasticsearch

I am completely new to web development and I want to set up a database search client on a website I am making because I do not want to write my own inefficient MySQL query strings. My plan is to use Elastic Search for this and my main question is:

Once my site is on a dedicated server somewhere, how do I install Elastic Search to the server, and/or what should I look for in a server so that I will be able to use Elastic Search?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a JRE,  that's about it as far just getting started.

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation.html for more details.

You'll probably want to run it as a service,  If your using Windows you can download installers here.  https://github.com/rgl/elasticsearch-setup/downloads

Hit me up if you need any help.